# Transaction mismatch in EntityFramework only

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I have a sproc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextImageRequest]
(...) AS

DECLARE @ReturnValue BIT
SET @ReturnValue = 1

-- Set paranoid level isolation: only one access at a time!
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE 
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY 
    ...
    UPDATE STATEMENT THAT THROWS FOREIGN KEY EXCEPTION           

    IF @@trancount > 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
    SET @ReturnValue = 0
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    SET @ReturnValue = 1
END CATCH 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET NOCOUNT ON

RETURN @ReturnValue   -- 0=success

GO
```

When i call this manually from Sql Server Management studio, i don't get any exception.
When I Call this through Entity Framework 6, i get

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

What am I doing wrong? The foreign key constraint is doing roll back but i am checking @@TRANCOUNT.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework 6 (EF6)
Add this line before ExecuteSqlCommand

db.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;

Answer (score 2):

It turns out EF6 wraps sproc call in its own transaction.
The workaround is to check if transaction is already open or not and only do BEGIN|COMMIT|ROLLBACK TRANSACTION if it isn't already open

Comment: what if you want to raise an error from stored procedure but prevent EF from rollback ?